A direct sum decomposition
I have tried to solve this problem. I am studying for an exam.
Let $V$ be a real finite-dimensional vector space and let $T \colon V \rightarrow V$ be and operator such that for some positive integer $n$ we have that $T^n = 0$ but $T^{n+1} \neq 0$. Prove that there exist subspaces $V_1, \dots, V_n \subseteq V$ such that $V = V_1 \oplus \dots \oplus V_n$, $V_i \neq \{0\}$ for all $i$, $T(V_i) \subseteq V_{i-1}$ for all $i = 2, \dots, n$, and $T(V_1) = 0$.
I have shown that for some $x \in V$, $x, Tx, \dots, T^{n-1}x$ are linearly independent and then I have tried to use that to construct the required spaces, but I haven't succeeded. If I suppose that $N \geq n$ is the dimension of $V$, then I can try to define $V_1 = \langle T^{n-1}x \rangle, V_2 = \langle T^{n-2}x \rangle, \dots, V_{n-1} = \langle Tx \rangle$ and then maybe extend $x$ to a basis of $V$ and call the space generated by these elements $V_n$. But then I would not have $T(V_n) \subseteq V_{n-1}$. This would be very easy if I had $n = N$.
Any help is appreciated.
Addendum: I think the following is another version of this problem but I am not sure.
Given an $n \times n$ real matrix $A$ and given that there are an $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a positive integer $k$ such that $A^kx = 0$ but $A^{k-1}x \neq 0$, show that there exist $A$-invariant subspaces $V_0$ and $V_1$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\mathbb{R}^n = V_0 \oplus V_1$, $A^n|_{V_0} = 0$, and $A|_{V_1} \colon V_1 \rightarrow V_1$ is invertible.

@FlynnFehre I think it does. Thank you.
